# Set GridView selector default

Tags: android, gridview

Within my Android app currently, I have a GridView that uses a custom adapter to populate it with multiple custom views.
 
This GridView is defined as follows:

```
<GridView
 android:id="@+id/grid"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
 android:isScrollContainer="false"
 android:listSelector="@drawable/selector"
 android:numColumns="3"
 android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

As you can see, I have defined a custom 'List Selector' that allows users to see what item of the grid view they have selected. 

What I want to know is the following, **Is it possible that when the grid view is created using the custom adapter the List Selector can be set to a default value and be visible?** (Currently the list selector only appears once a user has made a choice - *obviously*).

The custom GridView adapter is a simple adapter that extends `BaseAdapter`.

Many thanks

Comment: I dont understand exactly what you need. You mean you want items in gridview to be "selected" by default?

Comment: When the view is created, no item has been selected (i.e. the listSelector is not shown). What I want is the select to be shown when the view is initially created on an item by default

Comment: i'm stuck on this too, i need to create a selector for each item on gridview